# RabbitMQ always hold 1 message on queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I want to always hold one message on rabbitMQ's queue. When the second message is published first message will be consumed but the second message wait in a queue. When the third message is published the second message will be consumed. This is how things will go but I don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Note: I am using c#

Comment: You can check number of messages are pending in queue if you message count is greater than 1 then you should not consume message

Comment: Thanks. I will try